# count and group by in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have this tables in SQLAlchemy (database is in sqlite3):

Shot table

```
    shot_id    frame_id   ....
       1         10
       2         11
       3         10
       4         20
       5         20
       6         5
       7         20
       8         6
       .         .
       .         .
       .         .
```

In this table, `shot_id` is the `primary` key and `frame_id` is the `foreign` key. Now I want to write a query that gives me all the `shot_id`s that have the same `frame_id` and the number of `frame_id`s are larger or equal 2. For example, in the above table, I want the `shot_id` 1,3 for `frame_id=10` (they both have the same `frame_id` and there are 2 entries with `frame_id=10` )and `shot_id` 4,5,7 for `frame_id=20`. I have written this query:

`select shot_id,count(frame_id) from shot group by frame_id having count(frame_id)>=2;`

but it only gives me the shot_ids 3 and 7. It seems that `group by` only keeps the last element of each group. What should I do to get all the shots?

Comment: Forget about all the counting and grouping. Just join the table to itself. Oh, and it actually keeps arbitrary elements from each group, although I agree that in the absence of contradictory indexes, it will look like the 'last ones'.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you men by joining the table with itself? I need a way to count the number of `frame_id`. How can I do it with join?

Comment: Please share expected output also

Comment: You don't need to count anything. You're simply looking for values which appear more than once. JOINs are a fundamental concept of SQL, and too broad a topic to discuss here.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you don't need to 'count' anything; a self-join will suffice...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.frame_id = x.frame_id 
            AND y.shot_id <> x.shot_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, first of all, it is really slow and also does not give me all the shot_ids, it only gives one per frame_id, for example for frame_id=10, it only gives me shot_id 1 but not 3.

Comment: If it's slow it's (largely) because you haven't indexed your table. If it's incorrectly formatted it's because you haven't adequately explained how the desired result should appear.